Unable to save Selenium (Python) session after the machine restarts
I'm writing a set of test-cases using Selenium/Python. I have used the following code to launch a browser:
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=E:\\tests\\features\\storage\\profiles')

context.driver = Chrome(options=options)
context.driver.maximize_window()

The browser launches correctly, however, after I login to the site, it logs out automatically after some time. If I login to the same site, with exact same settings using a regular browser, the login lasts for several weeks.
My question is, how can I prevent Selenium from automatically logging out every once in a while? From what I have observed, the browser logs out every time the machine restarts, however, the profile data is still there, and Chrome is currently launching in the same browser.
